# `Log4`j не работает с `Tomcat9`

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, log4j

Всем привет. Настроил для своего веб-апл логгирование `log4j`. Локально все работает, файлы создаются, на сервере файлы не создаются. `OS Name:Linux` `3.13.0-79-generic`. Пробовал прописывать путь к файлу как полный , так и относительный. Все сообщения из кода типа:

```
logger.warn(new Date() + "TEST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
```

пишутся в файл `catalina.out`. Помогите понять в чем проблема, пжл.

Вот конфиг файла настроек:

```
  # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file,stdout
#Отдельный поток вывода для договоров:
log4j.logger.base.contracts=WARN,contractsfile


# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/app_Contracts.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}:%M:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.contractsfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.contractsfile.File=/usr/logs/contracts_package.log
log4j.appender.contractsfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.contractsfile.MaxFileSize=200MB
log4j.appender.contractsfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.contractsfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}:%M:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалите файл `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties`. Но лучше переименовать в logging.properties.bkp

Если не поможет, то добавьте в `JAVA_OPTS` в стартовом скрипте томката `-Dlog4j.debug` и посмотрите вывод. При этой опции log4j детально описывает процесс своей инициализации.

Comment: ` переименовать`  - не стартует томкет. ` добавьте в JAVA_OPTS в стартовом скрипте томката -Dlog4j.debug и ` подскажите где он лежит? Спасибо

Comment: Это {tomcat_home}/bin/startup.sh или .bat для windows